# Mouse doesn't work on my PC but works on other

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, mouse

My PC is HP 8300 SFF. First of all, I'd like to say that any other USB device that I connect to my PC is working. I have a mouse that worked flawlessly for 3 years (Zowie Mico) and today it is not working on both Ubuntu 18.04(kernel version 4.15.0-38-generic) and Windows 10(latest updates). This mouse is plug'n'play and doesn't require any special drivers. I have 10 USB ports on my PC and it doesn't work with any of them, however with one of them it is partially recognized by Linux.

Here's output of `dmesg` on Ubuntu:

```
[  128.621730] usb 3-3: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[  128.772521] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=1af3, idProduct=0001
[  128.772525] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfenter code herer=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  128.772527] usb 3-3: Product: ZOWIE Gaming mouse
[  128.772530] usb 3-3: Manufacturer: Kingsis Peripherals
[  128.775268] usbhid 3-3:1.0: can't add hid device: -71
[  128.775298] usbhid: probe of 3-3:1.0 failed with error -71
```

I tried executing `sudo modprobe -r usbhid; sudo modprobe usbhid` and it worked once, however doesn't work anymore. I tried plugging in my mouse to other PCs and it works without any problems. Could anyone explain what is the problem?

Comment: Do the opposite and see if another mouse has the same problem on your PC.

Comment: I'm currently using another USB mouse on my PC and it works fine.

Comment: Either the mouse is marginal and the other PC is tolerant, or your PC is marginal and your new mouse is more tolerant. Given that I have replaced a lot more mice than motherboards, I would bet on mouse problems, unless you have added something that draws a lot of power on the USB ports and makes the mouse not get the expected 5VDC?

Comment: Tried unplugging every other USB device and booting with only the mouse connected, still not working. Even tried booting from live Ubuntu usb drive, still the mouse is not recognized. I've used this mouse with this PC since may 2018.

Comment: Mouse connector could be a little out of tolerance na levo, and the USB connector on the PC could be a little out of tolerance to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Run a scan using your antivirus. If that doesn't work, Try re-installing the operating system. If that doesn't work, it's a safe bet that your motherboard/USB card is fried. Consider getting a replacement.

Comment: A bit premature, no?

Comment: The mouse doesnt work suddenly with no explanation, logical response is to run an AV scan. If it's a driver issue, then reinstalling the OS is the next step. If it's a hardware issue, then a replacement of the affected hardware is the next step.

Comment: How do you know the "affected hardware" is the motherboard and not the mouse?

Comment: Quote from OP's post: "I tried plugging in my mouse to other PCs and it works without any problems."